# Altium: White 2D outlines

Tags: pcb, components, altium

I started my component orientation when I suddenly see those white outlines around my components. And as I zoom in, they increase in number. Even when I tried to move my components elsewhere, they stayed right where they were. What are these? What's going on?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are the DRC (Design Rule Check) error markers. Circles generally show a short circuit, parallel lines show a broken connection, and there is a variety of others. Running the DRC again (Hotkey combo T-D) should remove them, and show you if you have any new errors.